# Create React App requires Node 4.0 or higher - Cannot Create React App after upgrading Node

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app, nvm

I tried to npx create-react-app and got the warning that CRA needs a higher version of node, so I upgraded node to the latest version(10.16.3) (npm 6.9.0) by following these commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo n 10.16.3
```

I tried to npx create-react-app app-name (and npm install -g create-react-app) again, but I kept getting this error when I CRA and I can no longer create a react app:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
...
Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact react react-dom react-scripts has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
..
info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose npm-session c251b1bfd58acfad
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 47ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
10 verbose stack     at regFetch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/index.js:76:23)
10 verbose stack     at fetchPackument (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/packument.js:42:10)
10 verbose stack     at packument (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/packument.js:20:10)
```

Create react app used to work when I had a node 6 version following these commands:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app-name
cd my-app-name
npm start
```

Should I uninstall CRA now by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app? Will that break my other CRA applications? Can npx and npm i -g create-react-app be used together?
Please help, I want to go back to creating react apps!

**FIXED:**
I ran the following:

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
$ nvm install 10.16.3
$ nvm use 10.16.3
$ sudo n prune
$ sudo npm uninstall -g n
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/n
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node 
$ npm list -g --depth 0
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib
├── create-react-app@3.1.1
└── npm@6.4.1
```

I uninstalled the n module because it was causing a lot of issues and reinstalled create-react-app globally. It works now, but I don't know why nvm's path shows 10.14.1 instead of 10.16.3.

Comment: You can try uninstall it wont break existing, alternatively try `nvm use 10.16.3`

Comment: @Rikin I uninstalled and reinstalled `npx` or `npm install -g cra` and use `nvm` but still getting the errors above. I'm thinking the problem might be the n module I installed. Can nvm and n install the same version at the same time?

Comment: Can you show what `node -v`. I am trying to cover all cases.

Comment: @Jon you can run uninstall - it won't break your existing CRA apps. The CRA that you install globally is the CLI - once a project has been created it doesn't need the globally installed version any more.

Comment: @JonathanIrwin I've run uninstall. I checked by `npm list -g --depth 0` and it shows path: `/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib` and n and npm modules only. I don't know why the node versions are not matching